# How shou FLVPlayback component

Tags: flash, flvplayback

I am trying to add a '`FLVPlayback`' component, as [described on the Adobe site](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/flvplayback_component/) to a very very simple flash movie.

I have no problem at all using this code to instantiate a FLVPlayback object dynamically.

```
import fl.video.*;

var flvPlayer:FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback();
addChild(flvPlayer);
//The next line assumes you have copied the skin file to the local directory
flvPlayer.skin = "./SkinUnderPlaySeekMute.swf"
flvPlayer.source = "http://www.helpexamples.com/flash/video/water.flv";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as your starting point, I got things working with that:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/flvplayback_programming.html